# Report with Mondrian cube not yielding results

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, mondrian

I am bit new to *iReport* and *JasperReports*. I have a mondrain cube and want generate reports from olap cube. In this direction I tried few things. I connected my OLAP cube's schema  as datasource . created new report and passed mdx to it. But I am not getting any output. Please  guide me on how to do this thing .

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you post your JRXML?

Comment: this is my mdx query : SELECT
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[Bytesent]})} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Feedback].[Feedback].Members})} ON ROWS
FROM [Basicsearch]

Comment: @Lisa I am getting mondrain internal error related to query parsing