# ireport issues working with mondrian cube

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am quiet new to ireport . Thing is I am using Ireport 5.1 to generate reports from my mondrian olap cube . I successfully established connection with my olap schema and data source . After that I created a new report and wrote following mdx query :

```
SELECT

NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Ho].[Ho].Members})} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[count]} ON ROWS
FROM [xyz]
```

It shows 3 records read when I click on preview data . But problem is it is not showing any fields nor any data is previewed . Moreover I am not getting any error .Please guide me on how to proceed further with this .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Report with Mondrian cube not yielding results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763863/report-with-mondrian-cube-not-yielding-results)